# Load data takes time in sqlldr

Tags: sql, oracle, bulkinsert, sql-loader

I have a text file of size 1 GB. I'm trying to load the data from the file into a table using **sqlldr** command. The loading is taking too much of time. How do I reduce the execution timing? Here is my code of.ctl file

```
load data
infile "D:\file1.txt"
into table LDR
fields terminated by ","
 (
    name,
    value
 )
```

Comment: How long is "too much"?

Comment: 10 minutes...and it was still running

Answer (score 1):

While loading data, do it in *parallel* and use *direct load path*, i.e.

```
sqlldr un/pw control=of.ctl parallel=true direct=true
```

Also, it would help if you dropped indexes and disabled triggers (if there are any on the LDR table); recreate/enable them after loading process is over.

Comment: Did the direct path and enabled parallel... But it is not helping much

Comment: What about indexes and triggers?

Comment: Not present in the table.